# how to email the output of a mysql command

Tags: mysql, mutt

I want to email the output of a MySQL command, I wrote the following script but it doesn't work, where am I going wrong?

```
mysql --user=me --password=00045344534 john_e56
SELECT table_schema,table_name,update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE update_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
INTO OUTFILE '/mysqlchanges.txt'
exit
mutt -s "mysql changes" me123@mail.com -a /mysqlchanges.txt < /mail.txt
```

Comment: Did you put all these commands into one shell script? You should move the part from  'SELECT' to 'exit' into a separate text file, and launch mysql like this: mysql --user=me --password=00045344534 john_e56 < separate-file.txt

Comment: I tried a separate file but ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE "/home/john/mysqlchanges.txt"
exit' at line 1

Comment: Remove `;` at the end of WHERE, it terminates your SQL command, and `INTO OUTFILE` becomes separate invalid command

Comment: OK but now it says ERROR 1086 (HY000) at line 1: File '/home/john/mysqlchanges.txt' already exists and if I delete the file and try again it says ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create/write to file '/home/john/mysqlchanges.txt' (Errcode: 13)

Comment: ps I am running the command as root

Comment: I made a new folder and made it writabe and added \! rm -rf /home/john/0/mysqlchanges.txt to the beginning of the script and now all is fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting?

I'm not sure how INTO OUTFILE works, but 99% it requires write access to the file you're telling it to write to. In your query the output file is right in the root (/) partition. I doubt the user mysql is run from allows to write there. If you're on *nix box, create a file in your home

```
touch /home/ubuntu/mysqlchanges.txt
sudo chown mysql:mysql /home/ubuntu/mysqlchanges.txt
```

in your shell first. Then to test you can do

```
su mysql
echo "" > /home/ubuntu/mysqlchanges.txt
```

and if that works with no error, you can modify your query to output to this file and mutt to get that file as attachment:

```
mysql --user=me --password=00045344534 john_e56
SELECT table_schema,table_name,update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE update_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
INTO OUTFILE '/home/ubuntu/mysqlchanges.txt'
exit
mutt -s "mysql changes" me123@mail.com -a /home/ubuntu/mysqlchanges.txt < /mail.txt
```

Assuming `ubuntu` is your user and mysql runs on behalf of `mysql` user.

**UPDATE**

If I understood your request right, you just need to receive the output of this SQL query:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name,update_time
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE update_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

onto your mailbox `me123@mail.com`

If it's not crucial to make it as attachment and just plain text in body is fine, then have a look at this bash command:

```
mysql -u me -p00045344534 -e 'SELECT table_schema,table_name,update_time FROM information_schema.tables WHERE update_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);' | mutt -s "mysql changes" me123@mail.com --
```

first it launches that query with output to `STDOUT`, then pipes it to `mutt`

Comment: root@john [/home/john]# 1mysqlmod.sh 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 510644
Server version: 5.5.42-cll MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

Comment: I tried what you said but I just get error     mysql> exit
Bye
/bin/1mysqlmod.sh: line 2: SELECT: command not found
/bin/1mysqlmod.sh: line 3: FROM: command not found
/bin/1mysqlmod.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/1mysqlmod.sh: line 4: `WHERE update_time > (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);'